# iOS didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: no URL although the app is opened by tapping a link

Tags: ios, url, launch

I am opening my app with a link handled by Branch:

> https://my.link?param=test

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
Branch.getInstance()?.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: { params, error in
    if error == nil {
        if let param = params?["param"] as? String {
            print(param)
        }
    }
}
```

This correctly prints `test` in the console.

However, I am also trying to fetch the url before, but trying to fetch `launchOptions?[.url]`, I get `nil` as a result.

So how can I get the url? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey`

Try this:

```
if let url = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.url] as? URL {
  // Your code
}
else if let activityDictionary = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.userActivityDictionary] as? [AnyHashable: Any] { //Universal link
    for key in activityDictionary.keys {
        if let userActivity = activityDictionary[key] as? NSUserActivity {
               if let url = userActivity.webpageURL {
                    // your code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer with the case of universal link (Maybe that is your case).